# Find element not directly in dom path

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a dom structure that looks something like (although a lot more complex)

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="remaining">132</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>clicky</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="remaining">142</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>clicky</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="remaining">152</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>clicky</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the divs with class `remaining` arn't directly in the dom path of the relative buttons.

How can I when the button is clicked, increment the relative `remaining` div by 1?

Comment: try making it simpler. call your class `remaining-1` `remaining-2` .... and so on

Comment: if i did that, how would I know which one i wanted to grab? as I do not have an event handler for each button, I have a global event handler that handles all buttons., also the rel attr is already in use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the nearest parent that contains a `.remaining` div ..

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $remain = $(this).closest(':has(div.remaining)').find('.remaining');
    $remain.text( parseInt($remain.text(),10) + 1);
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ujW2e/

Comment: Although this will work, depending on the real complexity of the structure, `:has` could be (relatively) slow, compared to given a parent a class. But that would have to be tested for the real structure. You got +1 from me :). You could also pass a function to `.text()`: `$remain.text(function(i, v){ return +v+1;});`

Comment: @Felix, yes indeed.. you got a +1 from me, too, as i think your solution is the most robust, but i posted this in case the OP structure was not modifiable...

Answer (score 7):

Give the common parent some meaningful class:

```
<div class="meaningful">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="remaining">152</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>clicky</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use [**`.closest()`**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [**`.find()`**](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $remaining = $(this).closest('.meaningful').find('.remaining');
    // change text...
});
```

Comment: +1 to my dear friend Felix nice indeed! great code. I'll put this question to my fav.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function() {     
    var workDiv = $(this).parents().find('.remaining').first();
    workDiv.text(parseInt(workDiv.text())+1);
});
```

Comment: erm... this answer makes no sense.

Comment: i just love you guyz.. from the link you provided Gaby: The .closest() method begins its search with the element itself before progressing up the DOM tree, and stops when item A matches the selector. So, if this is applied to the button onclick event...

Comment: @Dementic, pay close attention to the ***up*** the DOM.. `.remaining` is not up the dom, so it will never find it ... Second, the OP asks to find a div and increment its value... how does appending a div  helps ? also you probably meant `.append('<div>')` but that is also not relevant..

Comment: @Gaby - you are right, i missed that. but the happy trigger on the vote down is not really nice. i could have fixed the code ( after all im trying to help while working ) but you guyz should allways consider that mistakes are made, and dont be so fast on the trigger. a comment would have been sufficient for me to fix the code.

Comment: @Dementic, once you improve the code i will change my vote accordingly.. Your answer was there with a comment for about 15 minutes before i downvoted it and commented.. I routinely go back to downvotes i put, to check for changes in the answer.. It is not personal, I do it for the visitor to this page to take a clue as to what will work and what not...

Comment: Huh :) interesting point of view Hali, but I agree with Deme, sometimes you'll rather erase the answer having -1, -2 rather than giving it a second look and even get a correct answer mark! kinda stress but fun! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var remainingdiv = $(this).closest('.meaningful').find('.remaining');
   remainingdiv.html(parseInt(remainingdiv.html(), 10) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Never forget to pass the radix if you use `parseInt`!

Comment: Added the radix although I don't really expect numbers with 0 appended to it. Please use the closest instead of the double parent I suggested, it was made to do that ;)

Comment: This should be a comment on @Felix's answer, since it builds on it. Right now, it is taken out of context and it means nothing without the suggestions in felix's answer..